# AJAX POST not actually sending POST data with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, ajax

I want to submit a form to my Django back end using an AJAX post. I have multiple forms on the page but only want the one the user submits to be the one that sends.

The form is held in a modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class='content-section'>
        <form method="POST" id="form{{ prod.id }}" class="showform" value="{{ prod.id }}" >
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ prod.id }}" name="prodid">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class='form-group'>
                {{ form|crispy}}
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class='form-group'>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info submit-form" value={{prod.id}} form="form{{ prod.id }}"
            >Save
            To Profile</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

When the submit button is pressed, it triggers the following AJAX :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.submit-form', function () {

        var thisButton = $(this)[0]
        var prodID = $(this).val();
        var form = $("form" + prodID);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            headers:{
                "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            url: '/ajax/validate_showadd/',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'json',
            data: {
                'form': form.serialize(),
                "prodID":prodID,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("sent")
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

However, within Django whenever I try access any of these values it just returns 'None' and the QueryDict for the POST request is empty.

Thank you

Comment: If you display the console in your browser and activate the `XHR` display, you'll be able to see the actual POST request being sent from the browser. You can click on it and in the `params` tab, you'll see what data you're sending. Could you provide a screenshot of it? (example: http://images3.programmersought.com/636/49/49fcd3fc919f1304f0bc478d509c16e4.png)

Comment: 'form': form.serialize(), this line is maybe the culprit. try to pass form values individually. print form.serialize() in console

Comment: You’re sending json so obviously the QueryDict is empty. Send your data as x-www-form-urlencoded (and remove `contentType` setting).